# Не могу настроить сервер Apache

Tags: apache, apache2.4

Пытаюсь установить локальный веб-сервер для теста сайта.

В `httpd.conf` `ServerRoot` указан как `С:/server/apache`, однако, при попытке установить `httpd.exe` в консоли выпадает ошибка:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 39 of
>   C:/server/apache/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory

что, очевидно, указывает на невалидный путь, однако, я не могу понять почему. Пожалуйста, укажите на мою ошибку.

Comment: потому что слеши не туда смотрят мб?

Comment: поменял, так же =(

Comment: дак директория-то существует? файлы апача там расположены?

Comment: ну да, папка server с папкой apache лежит на диске С как и прописано в пути

Comment: Дак в ней апач установлен, или левая папка? [`ServerRoot` должен указывать на директорию инсталляции самого сервера](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot).

Comment: хотя, да, `httpd.conf` то внутри лежит.

Comment: ну да, врядли сам инсталлер запустился бы еслиб его там не было :D

Comment: `httpd` это уже не инсталлятор, а исполняемый файл сервера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61235/discussion-between-arc-and-teran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно было изменить `C:/server/apache` в `ServerRoot` на `/server/apache` и все заработало. Не знаю с чем это связано.